# JavaScript While Loop Error

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        ...........
        While Loops 
        ...........
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var a = 1;
            while(a < 10) {
              document.write("Hello World<br />")
            };
            a++;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my while loop code when I run my code in Firefox browser or other browser like Chrome in Firefox it crashes and in Chrome it only loading occurs Right now I am following tutorial of bucky roberts from site:http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=10&number=20
I have Entered the Same code which he has written in his video but then to its not working ...please some one help to find problems regarding While Loop please .. Thanks In Advance.... I have set my Variable value as `a = 1` And setting it as `a<10` and I am Incrementing it as `a++`  but it is looping infinite times ..

Comment: Looks like an Infinite Loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop never terminates because `a++` is outside of your `while` loop. Hence it never terminates as expected. If you look at his code again, the post incrementing of `a` is in the loop:

```
var a = 1;
while(a<10){
   document.write("Hello World<br />")
   a++;
};
```

Compare this with [his code](http://youtu.be/QPFW_0blw9w?t=5m10s) and yours and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @Varun did you add `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Comment: @xlm That's not needed.

Comment: @fzzle +1 thanks for clarifying that! Didn't know that, I've always included it when writing JS.

Comment: @Varun How is it not working? What output or error do you get?